# WordPress include file at header not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to include some php files in header.php. I use the script below :-

```
get_template_part( 'custom/tos_functions');
```

However get_template_part doesn't work for me, so I use include which works fine.

```
include (TEMPLATEPATH . "custom/tos_functions.php");
```

The issue is, if I put this line in header.php, I want to use some of the functions in custom template , say profile.php. In profile.php the file is as though not being called at all. I can't get the data I need in profile.php.

Then I tried to take out the include script from header, and place it in profile.php and the data I need can be called perfectly fine. 
This will be an issue as there will be many custom php pages I need to create, thus every page will call the include script.

Question, why is it that the file cannot be called from header.php ? The data can only be retrieved within header.php and any custom page that calls the header, couldn't get the data from the include file.

Anyway I can fix this so that I can place the include file in the header.php?

Thank you!

Comment: Why you are not including those functions to functions.php ?

Comment: It's a list of API for another system, thus would like to separate them out.

Comment: That is **the wrong place** to include them.  Include the file from your functions.php (don't put the functions in functions.php, but rather **require_once** your file inside of functions.php).

Comment: Actually the functions file is just an example, I have two other files to include too. Thus I can't put in functions.php
It's a custom page where I need to call some APIs to a company's system, so it's like a custom php file.

Comment: I will try the require_once inside functions.php. Thanks a lot for the replies all.

Comment: @cale_b putting the files and require_once inside functions.php works like a charm. Thank you very much! I can't mark your answer as the correct answer in the comment. If you want, you can answer it separately and I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Sylph if it conatins functions include it in functions.php and if it is a template part use get_template_part() to use it, in no situation you are going to use include in template file.

Comment: Thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than including files in the theme template files (such as `header.php`), you should include them in the theme's `functions.php` file.

Including them in the template files is almost always too late in the WP run for it to be useful, and it may cause unexpected results and unexpected output in your templates.

Instead, in your functions.php file, do something like so:

```
require_once 'custom/tos_functions.php';
```

Then, your API code is available where you need it, and it is in the "right" place and consistent with the "WordPress way".

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!